# Remove border from image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added an border for images. But some images are missing, and for these images i have added an error message. I do not want any border for images which are missing but i am still getting it. Is there any way in jquery that i can remove border from images which are not actually present on the specified path.
Thanks
Romi.

**EDIT**

I hav bulk of images path, in which some of the image paths are not valid and for these invalid paths i do not want to add an error. I have single css for all image path.I cant differentiate between these. Is there any other way to do this.

Comment: i think you should care of not showing the image tags of pictures that aren't available.

Comment: Why do you want to display broken images?

Comment: I juss want to show an error message for broken images, but when i am doing it it also adds an border.

Comment: @Scott - I recently dealt with a client that insisted on uploading 4M images through his CMS (even though I told him the image-resizer failed >2M. To combat this, I added default images, regex (for some ridiculous characters he was using as well)....I had to client-proof the site much more than one would have thought necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i will use david code to handle missing images

http://davidwalsh.name/custom-missing-image-jquery

use the idea to set border - 0

```
$("img").error(function () {
      $(this).css("border", "none");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for images that you don't want to add borders to, just give them a class name then set up the css

```
<img src='image.png' class='no-border' />
```

the css:

```
img.no-border {
   border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<img src="broken" onerror="this.style.border='none';"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS approach, like others have said, but utilizing inheritance of the markup rather than targeting images (per se).

```
.container { }
.container img, .container a img { border:1px solid black }
```

So IF there are images present inside that area of your layout, they get a border - otherwise, they don't.

This approach also negates the need for unique IDs for each image, and separate classes (though classes may help, depending).

Answer (score -1):

You can use standard javascript to change the class of an element:

```
document.getElementById('IdOfElement').className = 'missing';
```

Then set up some CSS to give any element with a missing class no border:

```
.missing {
    border: none;
}
```

Each image would need a unique ID:

```
<img src="" id="image1">
```

Comment: But why would you use standard JS if you already have jQuery in the page? I am normally all for plain JS, but not if I have already added jQuery to the page

Comment: Yes i want a solution in Jquery. If you have please suggest.